# OSX Leopard - throttle a shared internet connection

Tags: macos, networking, osx-leopard

I'm running a Core Duo Macbook pro and I'm trying to emulate a 3G connection for connected devices via wifi internet connection sharing. I've tried a few options (e.g. speedlimit) but they only impact the macbook's browser and not the connected devices. Are there any other options out there? I'm running leopard as anything more modern overheats the system.

I have a T60 as an alternative, but the intel 3935abg chipset isn't supported by any windows 7 VirtualMiFi tools, and I need to connect Android devices to this network.

Answer (score 3):

I found this very useful tool for testing various types of connection. 
Slowy app: http://slowyapp.com/

It has some preset (56K, EDGE, 3G, LTE and DSL) but allows you to set various parameters to limit the network traffic to a specified destination port or interface.

I recommend everyone to try it.

Answer (score 2):

You are in luck - your version of OSX should still support IPFW; so one can do

```
 sudo ipfw pipe 1 config bw 15KByte/s
 sudo ipfw add 1 pipe 1 src-port 80
```

to cut down anything, in above example for port 80. Be sure to make the rule cover the traffic going through your mac. See http://intrarts.com/throttled.html
or http://www.hanynet.com/waterroof/ for friendlier tools.

Beyond Leopard - you want to look at pfctl. http://blog.segment7.net/2009/07/27/bandwidth-limiting-with-pf-and-altq and http://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/queueing.html are good starts. Note though that by default you cannot use ALTQ (it is not in the default OSX kernel).